# Extension of Measures (Dynkin's Theorem)

Tags: measure-theory

For simplicity, given a single point space $\Omega:=\{x_0\}$.

Consider the $\cap$-stable collection $\mathcal{S}:=\{\varnothing\}$ and the set function $\mu:\mathcal{S}\to\mathbb{R}_+:\mu(\varnothing):=0$.

Now, Dynkin's theorem tells us that every measure on the generated sigma-algebra is unique.
But, there are many measures in this case. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is a $\cap$-stable system such that $\mu$ is **$\sigma$-finite with respect to $A$** and if $\mu =\nu$ on $A$, then $\mu = \nu$ on $\sigma(A)$.

Here, $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite with respect to $A$ if$\Omega = \bigcup_n A_n$ with $A_n \in A$ and $\mu(A_n)<\infty$ for each $n$.

This is not true in your case.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot apply Dynkin's theorem to $\mathcal{S}=\{\emptyset\}$ since a crucial assumption is violated: There has to exist a sequence $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathcal{S}$ such that $A_n \uparrow \Omega$. In this case, this means that $\mathcal{S}$ has to satisfy $\{x_0\} \in \mathcal{S}$.

Comment: The $A_n$ also have to satisfy $\mu(A_n)<\infty$ (which is clear for probability measures). Otherwise, consider $A = \{(a,b) \mid a<b \}$ and $\mu$ the counting measure on $\Bbb{R}$, $\nu=\infty \lambda$, where $\lambda $ is Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @PhoemueX You are right, in general we have to assume that $\mu(A_n)<\infty$. But in this case, we don't have to this since any measure on $\Omega=\{x_0\}$ is uniquely determined by $\mu(\{x_0\})$.